# Magento 2 layered navigation no results

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I have a problem with the Layered Navigation from Magento 2 in the sense that it doesn`t show me results when applying certain atribute filters. the only filter that shows me results is the price.

I have created 4 other attributes (Lab, format, season, etc.) by assigning the value "Filterable (with results)". These attributes that I created are displayed correctly in the Layered Navigation menu and also indicate the number of products that each attribute has.

[image: Layered Navigation Menu - Magento2]

But when I click on any of them I get back the message that no products with those atributes were found.

[image: Layered Navigation Results Empty]

I tried to clean the Cache, to re-index and to change the magento mode to production but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below items on the admins?

> - Enabled = yes
> - Product in website = yes
> - Product in category = yes
> - Stock status in stock = yes
> - Visibility = catalog, search
> - Reset index, Reindex

after, run the below commands.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Please let me know if it works for you.